# How to get join of two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two `MySQL` tables `single_match_master` and `team_master`.

`single_match_master` columns => match_id, team1_id, team2_id, team1_score, team2_score

`team_master` columns =>  team_id, team_name

I want to select `match_id` and the respective name of teams from the `team_master` table.

here is the query which i have written it gives empty set as result;

```
select  a.match_id,a.team1_id,a.team2_id,a.team1_score,
        a.team2_score,a.status,
        b.team_name
from single_match_master a,team_master b
where a.team1_id=b.team_id 
and a.team2_id=b.team_id;
```

Comment: So can you show us the amended SQL with a JOIN in it that you have tried to write?

Comment: I have added the query which I have tried.

Comment: But that does not contain a JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - using join of multiple instance of team_master table

```
select 
     a.match_id,a.team1_id,a.team2_id,a.team1_score,a.team2_score,
     a.status,b.team_name as team1name, b1.team_name as team2name
from 
single_match_master a inner join team_master b
on a.team1_id=b.team_id inner join team_master b1
on a.team2_id=b1.team_id
```

Comment: it still gives me an empty set